# Sometimes the screenshot image via adb can not be opend

Tags: python, adb, python-imaging-library

I am taking some screenshots via adb from my android device (OnePlus 5) to recognize with googles tesseract if there is a specified word inside the page.

Usually it takes 5-8 screenshots with a 1.5 second delay from each other. The first 2-4 screenshots can be opend but then it throws the error and can´t be opend with PIL, Paint.net or on the phone itself.

```py
from adb.client import Client as AdbClient
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import os


# The Method with the Problem
# adb package is pure-python-adb
# after 2-4 calls of the method the error ocures
def get_screen(device):
    device.shell("screencap -p /sdcard/pgrinder/screen.png")
    device.pull("/sdcard/pgrinder/screen.png", "screen.png")
    screens = ""
    try:
        **screens = Image.open('screen.png')**
    except Exception:
       print("error with image opening")
       return -1
    return screens
```

The current error is: OSError: cannot identify image file 'C:\Users\kelle\PycharmProjects\PGrinder\tmp\screen.png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the bug for me was to remove the pgrinder directory in this path: /sdcard/pgrinder/screen.png.

I thought it would generate the directory if it doesn´t exist but that wasn´t the case. I don´t no why it worked sometimes and sometimes not. But since I changed it, it worked every time.